# What does this PHP regular expression do?

Tags: php, regex

```
public function getBlock( $tag )
   {
     preg_match ('#<!-- START '. $tag . ' -->(.+?)
         <!-- END '. $tag . ' -->#si', $this->content, $tor);
     $tor = str_replace ('<!-- START '. $tag . ' -->', "", $tor[0]);
     $tor = str_replace ('<!-- END '  . $tag . ' -->', "", $tor);
     return $tor;
}
```

Does anyone know what this function does?

Comment: It’s a really bad way to match and replace blocks. Dynamic regular expressions pretty much always are. Where did you get this?

Comment: Depends on what `$tag` is.. honestly how are we supposed to know?

Comment: tag defines where content is going to placed, just like using template management

Comment: At least post `$tag` content... Also it seems you already asked about it a while ago >.> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196604/regular-expression-with-subexpression

Comment: I think you should address this question to the one who wrote it, otherwise learn about [the basics of regex](http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/).

Comment: the 2 lines starting with `$tor =` shouldn't be needed, as $tor[1] holds the text between the tags

Comment: After some thought I think you are right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function getBlock( $tag )
   {
     //below finds the start tag, then matches any character multiple times
     // until it finds <!-- END $tag -->, store the result in $tor
     preg_match ('#<!-- START '. $tag . ' -->(.+?)
         <!-- END '. $tag . ' -->#si', $this->content, $tor);

     //the # is the delimiter, with s meaning treat as a single line 
     // so . matches \r\n for example. and i means insensitive 
     $tor = str_replace ('<!-- START '. $tag . ' -->', "", $tor[0]);
     $tor = str_replace ('<!-- END '  . $tag . ' -->', "", $tor);

     //remove the line with start on then remove line with end on.

     return $tor;
     //return what was between the two lines.
}
```

Ive added some comments to the function, Hope they make it more clear

Comment: What's the 's' mean in '#si'?

Comment: "with s meaning treat as a single line". without this . will not match a new line

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it removes

```
'#<!-- START '. $tag . ' -->'
```

and

```
'<!-- END '  . $tag . ' -->'
```

from the text in $this->content, and returns all of the text which was between those comments.